# Return object as interface from generic method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, interface, factory-method

I have one interface `InterfaceBase` and some interfaces derived from it `Interface1, Interface2`. Next I have classes that are implementing the `InterfaceX` interfaces, not the base one.

Now, i am beginner in generics and so many new approaches in this made  great mess in my head :( . I want to create factory (static class) where I call something like

```
Interface1 concrete1 = Factory.Get<Interface1>();
```

Here is my (sample) implementation of factory, that does not work:

```
  public static class Factory {

    public static T Get<T>() where T: InterfaceBase{

      Type type = typeof(T);

      //return new Concrete1() as T; // type T cannot be used with the as
      //return new Concrete1() as type; //type not found
      //return new Concrete1(); // cannot implicitly convert
      //return new Concrete1() as InterfaceBase; //cannot convert IBase to T
      //return new Concrete1() as Interface1; //cannot convert Interface1 to T
    }
  }
```

What I want to achieve is hide the classes (they are webservice handlers) from the rest of the application to exchange them lightly. I wanted use the factory as the classes will be singletons and they will be stored in Dictionary inside the factory, so the factory can spread them across the application through this method, but as interfaces..
Maybe i am not using the constraints correctly
am I doing smthing wrong? is my approach bad? can be there something better, maybe the whole architecture shoul be reworked? diagram to show better the [architecture](http://i260.photobucket.com/albums/ii22/cccp14/other/newArch.png). The factory is not in it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methinks what you are looking for is a "Poor-Man Dependency Injection". I guess you should use a real IoC container for that, there are a lot of options (Unity, Castle Windsor, Ninject...).

But anyway, If you insist in doing it by yourself, go with what @Sergey Kudriavtsev is recomending. Just make sure that, for each interface, you return the proper concrete class. Something like this:

```
public interface InterfaceBase { }
public interface Interface1 : InterfaceBase { }
public interface InterfaceX : InterfaceBase { }

public class Concrete1 : Interface1 { }
public class ConcreteX : InterfaceX { }

public static class Factory
{
    public static T Get<T>()
        where T : InterfaceBase
    {
        if (typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (T)(InterfaceBase)new Concrete1();
        }
        // ...
        else if (typeof(InterfaceX).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (T)(InterfaceBase)new ConcreteX();
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type " + typeof(T).Name, "T"); // Avoids "not all code paths return a value".
    }
}
```

And you call it by passing the interface reference to the factory:

```
var instance = factory.Get<Interface1>();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's the same as @Sergey Kudriavtsev proposed.

Comment: +1 for identifying the "real" solution (inversion of control) rather than just the immediate problems described in the question.  The broad description of the OP's requirements ("hide the classes ... and exchange them lightly") is a good statement of the purpose of IoC.

Comment: But after leaving my first comment, I realized that this solution won't compile because Concrete1 is not known to derive from InterfaceBase.  The runtime type check `typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` doesn't fix that because the compiler doesn't take it into account.

Comment: @Diego: it does work, I don't know why it doesn't work for the OP though. And yes, it is an expansion of Sergey's answer, that's why I'm citing him (and also +1nd his answer).

Comment: I'm trying to compile this but it doesn't compile. That's why I said it doesn't work.

Comment: @Diego: OK, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Diego see my answer for one reason why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Diego: Sorry, you were right. But basically the only thing missing was a intermediary cast to `InterfaceBase`. See my edited answer.

Comment: @phoog you are right your edit2 explains clearly why this approach doesn't compile. Thanks!

Comment: @rsenna now it works fine :) thanks! But I think this solution doesn't scale well, for every new sub-interface you add you need to add a new branch to the if.

Comment: @rsenna The cast to InterfaceBase could also be a cast to `object`.  By (upcasting and) downcasting, you're telling the compiler to insert a runtime type check, so it no longer complains at compile time about the cast.  I'm now curious whether the `as` solution or the cast-up-then-down solution is more or less efficient -- or perhaps it generates the same IL?  If I find some time later today, I'll check.

Comment: @Diego You could define the interface vs concrete type mapping in your App.Config file, and then read it in the factory method. That's basically the Unity approach, for instance. But I won't add that to my answer: I do have a real work you know, and I already use Unity for that kind of thing. :)

Comment: @rsenna, you are right, that would be a better way to do this :D

Comment: @phoog I understand your point, and maybe there is a better option, if you are really concerned about saving some more nanoseconds... Just remember that the OP wants to instantiate **web-service handlers**: which means that he has bigger bottlenecks to worry about. :)

Comment: @rsenna the IL/efficiency question was more of academic interest about the mechanics of the language than of practical interest.  Clearly if there is a difference in performance it will be infinitesimal compared to any other performance factors.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
return (T)(new Concrete1());
```

Also the code for calling factory method should be like this:

```
Interface1 concrete1 = Factory.Get<Interface1>();
```

Comment: +1 But I'd use `return new Concrete1() as T;` and check for `null` in calling code.

Comment: sergey - no it works not, cannot convert Concrete1 to T, but thanks for the factory calling :) corrected

Comment: @Zavael Does `Concrete1` implement `InterfaceBase`?

Comment: @Yuck: `as` will not work here without some adjustments; please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693463/operator-as-and-generic-classes

Comment: no, it implements Interface1 directly, which derives from InterfceBase.. its written in Q

Comment: sergey - but i must to add in where clause the "class" no? and it means then that class should be passed in method or am I wrong?

Comment: What comiler will say about `return (T)((InterfaceBase)(new Concrete1()));` ?

Comment: @Zavael Interfaces don't *derive* from each other. That's what you're doing wrong. They merely describe contracts.

Comment: @Yuck but interfaces can inherit from one another, and "derive from" is a reasonable way to describe that relationship.  How else would you describe `interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable { ... }`?

Comment: Oops, Correction to earlier (deleted) comment: @Zavael "class" actually means "reference type", so it includes interfaces as well as classes. Similarly, "struct" means "value type", so it includes enums.  (Earlier comment incorrectly said that "struct" means "reference type" too!)

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev - it does compile, but it seems to me dangerous as the compiler enabled <code>StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder)((object)new Concrete1());</code> too... PS: how to write code in comments to have that gray background? :)

Comment: @Zavael: The cast itself might be dangerous because it does not really check the types (if you use `(object)`). But in your case you can cast to `InterfaceBase` instead (this will fail if you try to use it with `StringBuilder` and ensures some safety). To write the code with gray background, enclose it in backticks ( ` ). For more formatting check the link "Help" below "Add Comment" button.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one part of your question:

```
return new Concrete1() as T; // type T cannot be used with the as
```

Type `T` cannot be used with `as` because `T` is not known to be a reference type.  You can constrain the class to be a reference type with the `where T : class [, ...]` constraint.  This will allow you to use the `as` operator, assuming, of course, that you don't need to be able to use this method with value types.

<s>**EDIT**</s>

Having said that, I prefer rsenna's answer.  Since you know at compile time that the direct cast will work, it makes more sense to use a direct cast than `as`.  I also agree with his recommendation that you investigate "real" IoC containers, but I would add that a strong understanding of generics will be very useful to you as you learn about them.  Since you say that you are a beginner in generics, an exercise like this one is probably a *good idea*, because it will help you learn about generics, and give you a better appreciation for the value that IoC containers can add.

**EDIT 2**

I see another problem:  You constrain T to be InterfaceBase, and then you cast Concrete1 to T.  Concrete1 is not known to derive from T!  Which is of course why you use the `as` cast.  So the answer is, add the `class` constraint and you should be fine.

**EDIT 3**

As rsenna points out, you can also get a runtime type check with an upcast and downcast:

```
return (T)(object)new Concrete1();
```

or

```
return (T)(InterfaceBase)new Concrete1();
```

I wonder how this compares in terms of efficiency with

```
return new Concrete1() as T;
```

I'll check later today if I find some time to do so.

Comment: Regarding your new edits: If we add the `class` constraint, we cannot use `Factory.Get<Interface1>()` anymore.

Comment: @rsenna If you think it's not possible because `Interface1` is not a class then you are mistaken.  As a generic parameter constraint, "class" means "any reference type", just as "struct" means "any value type".  Confusing, but true.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `class` only requires the type parameter to be a reference type.

Comment: @rsenna no need to apologize :) this entire exchange has been somewhat confusing.

Comment: +1 uaaaaa great thanks, i tought the class means that it needs to be a class!

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this

```
public static class Factory {

public static T Get<T>() where T: InterfaceBase{

  return (T) new Concrete1();
}
```

Cannot be typed safely. You cannot guarantee that the method will be invoked with T == Concrete1. T can be ANY subtype of InterfaceBase, Concrete1 is just one of those subtypes and not necessarily the same T, therefore the compiler won't allow you to cast to T, the same way it won't allow you to cast to string or any other unrelated type.

Activator.CreateInstance() is one way of handling that: CreateInstance does guarantee that the built instance is of type T, which is the expected output value of the method.

Comment: But the OP wants to be able to call `Get<Interface1>()` in which case `Activator.CreateInstance<Interface1>()` will fail.  He needs a way of mapping `Interface1` to `Concrete1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that T is a subtype of InterfaceBase (where T : InterfaceBase) then you can make the return type of the Get method be InterfaceBase:

```
public static InterfaceBase Get<T>() where T : InterfaceBase
{        
    return new Concrete1();
}
```

This method can be invoked using a sub-interface of InterfaceBase as T:

```
InterfaceBase ib = Factory.Get<Interface1>();
```

If you pass anything but a sub-interface of InterfaceBase as T the compiler will complain.

I think this is a better approach but as @phoog points it only works with concrete classes for the T type parameter:

```
public static T Get<T>() where T : InterfaceBase
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (t.IsAbstract || t.IsInterface)
{
        throw new ArgumentException(@"Only non-abstract classes supported as T type parameter.");
}
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Comment: I just left the first line of the code posted in the question

Comment: This won't work either, since Concrete1 is not known to derive from T.  They both derive from InterfaceBase, but that's not enough.

Comment: Yes, this work, I'm trying it on a foo project while I'm answering.

Comment: @Diego "this won't work either" was in reference to `return new Concrete1();` -- does that work?  I don't think it should.  Can you post a complete example that shows that it does?  Of course, Activator.CreateInstance<T> compiles, but the OP wants to pass an interface and then return a type that implements the interface.  In that case, you'll get an exception at run time.

Comment: @phoog Regarding the Activator.CreateInstance<T> you are right, if you pass an interface or if you pass an abstract class it will throw an exception at runtime. You can only use non-abstract classes for T and a check needs to be added to enforce this. I'm updating the code, but my feeling is that both solutions are fragile.