# Safely cast a Generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, oftype

I have a piece of code that attempts to cast and return an object called `m_obj` depending on a given generic type. Here is the code:

```
private IObject m_obj;
public bool TryGetAs<T>(out T value) where T :IObject
{
    value = m_obj as T; // The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

    // value = (T)m_obj; This compiles!

    if (value != null)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I know that if `m_obj` were a list, I could do this:

```
private readonly IList<Object> m_objects;

internal IList<T> Collect<T>() where T : IObject
{
    return m_objects.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to solve the problem in the first code example. Here is the original code again:

```
public interface IObject
{
    
}
```

This is my proposed solution:

```
    public bool TryGetAs<T>(out T value) where T :IObject
    {
        value = default(T);
        if (!(m_obj is T))
            return false;

        value = (T)m_obj;
        return true;
    }
```

I would like to know if my solution is correct and if there are any better or more elegant ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @mjwills Edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Generic Types with As operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253439/using-generic-types-with-as-operator)

Comment: If you had `public struct Bob : IObject
    { }` and `m_obj` was `null`, what would you expect `TryGetAs` to set `value` to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as` operator is reserved for reference types. If `T` is always a reference type, the solution is to add a `class` constraint to `TryGetAs<T>`. If `T` can also be a value type, this is not an option. In this case you can use the `is` operator:

```
public bool TryGetAs<T>(out T value) where T : IObject
{
    if(m_obj is T)
    {
        value = (T)m_obj;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In C# 7.0 you can simplify it like this (and improve performance since you don't need an `is` cast and then another type cast):

```
public bool TryGetAs<T>(out T value) where T : IObject
{
    if(m_obj is T tValue)
    {
        value = tValue;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sefe, this is exactly what I meant. I found it by the time you posted this I will mark it as an answer though,

Answer (score 4):

The [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) keyword works with reference types.

The compiler doesn't know that `T` is indeed a reference type, so it shouts at you and won't compile.
You can tell the compiler that it's a reference type by adding the [`class` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) before the `IObject` constraint. Now you can safely cast.

Comment: Thanks Ofir, can you please help me understand why .OfType<T>() seems to safely cast, although we are dealing with IObject here again!

Comment: `OfType` uses `is` not `as`. https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @mjwills That is exactly what I mean! How in .OfType() 'is' works despite the fact that we do not know IObject is a class or struct but in the above code the compiler does not allow it.

Comment: Because `is` doesn't require reference types. `as` needs it because of the null behaviour of it

Comment: :D you do not understand what I mean! I edited the question with the right answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
public bool TryGetAs<T>(out T value) where T : class, IObject
{
    value = m_obj as T;

    return (value != null);
}
```

will act the same as your final solution, as well as likely being faster (since a null check is faster than an `is` check).

*There is no benefit in **not** including the `class` modifier, if all of your  `IObject` implementations are reference types (`class`) not value types (`struct`).*

Comment: The problem with you answer is that you do not consider that the T can be not a class.

Comment: Even double struct in C# implements for example IComparable. You will be okay if you approach it with caution.